# Critical Error after Edit Master Page - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, compiler-errors

After I edit my master page in Sharepoint (even a simple edit like just add a enter), my website give me this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPBr6.gif

I tried to check the log files and could not found the ID of the Error and if I do a undo-check-out, the website go back to work. Somebody haved any issue like that?

Comment: you should find something in the uls with the correlationid. make sure to check all frontends and check if the tracing service is running, and logging is setup in CA

Comment: tried iisreset and not worked. I already checked (many times) the uls with not sucess and all the services in the other sites in the same server are okay.

Comment: see if this helps, http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/01/fix-for-this-page-has-encountered-critical-error.html